# Trouble pulling Field Value from List inside Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Goal:  I have an Index View that shows all open records from Table (ICS_Transactions).   Currently it shows ALL records.  I am trying to do something quick to filter out any records that DO NOT have a match in secondary table (ICS_Orders).  No need to show any records without orders associated.

I have this almost working (I think). I believe my problem is this area

```
var MyReqs = q.FirstOrDefault().RequsitionNumber;
```

The foreach works, except that it's only grabbing the fist records's Requisition Number each time.  And I understand why (FirstorDefault).  But, I don't know what to replace that with - in order to keep looping through each time.  I tried simply removing the (.FirstOrDefault()) but that syntax is not correct.

Here is the full Index Controller Code

```
List<ICS_Transactions> newqList = new List<ICS_Transactions>();
var q = db.ICS_Transactions.Where(s => s.OpenClosed == "Open");
q = q.Where(s => s.TransType == "New Internal Order");

var MyReqs = q.FirstOrDefault().RequsitionNumber;

foreach (ICS_Transactions trans in q)
{
//do whtaever you need to see if this trans should be includxed

var z = db.ICS_Orders.Where(s => s.RequisitionNumber == MyReqs );

if (z == null)
{
// do nothing
          
else 
{ 
newqList.Add(trans); 
}
           
}

return View(newqList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `MyReqs` to `var MyReqs = trans.RequsitionNumber;` and move it inside `foreach`
2. Change:

```
if (z == null)
{
    // do nothing
}       
else 
{ 
    newqList.Add(trans); 
}
```

to:

```
if(z.Any())
{ 
    newqList.Add(trans); 
}
```

Or just if you have relations set up you can try to do it in one query, looking something like this (not sure about relations you have):

```
var newqList = db.ICS_Transactions
    .Where(s => s.OpenClosed == "Open");
    .Where(s => s.TransType == "New Internal Order")
    .Where(s => s.ICS_Orders.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Or at least fetch all needed `RequsitionNumber`'s from `ICS_Orders` in one query to db and filter list:

```
var newqList = db.ICS_Transactions.Where(s => s.OpenClosed == "Open");
    .Where(s => s.TransType == "New Internal Order")
    .ToList();

var reqsInOrders = db.ICS_Orders
    .Where(s => newqList.Select(n => n.RequisitionNumber).Contains(s.RequisitionNumber))
    .Select(s => s.RequisitionNumber)
    .ToList();

newqList  = newqList
    .Where(t => reqsInOrders.Contains(t.RequisitionNumber))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Guru Stron - Thank you!  Thank you to everyone who answered.  I believe all were great.  I opted for your first solution example, as it made the most sense, with the direction I had already gone.  And I appreciate all of the additional information to help me understand.   The other replies were also GREAT.

Comment: @ExecChef was glad to help! Also you can upvote other answers;)

Answer (score 1):

What about using Select()?

```
var z = q.Select(p => p.RequisitionNumber);
```

Now you have a collection containing just the RequisitionNumber field from each object in your "q" collection.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you can combine a Where with Any query to get what you're looking for all in one go with Linq.

```
var openInternalTransactions =
    db.ICS_Transactions
        .Where(s => s.OpenClosed == "Open")
        .Where(s => s.TransType == "New Internal Order");

var openInternalTransactionsWithOrders =
    openInternalTransactions.Where(trans => 
        db.ICS_Orders.Any(order =>
            order.RequisitionNumber == trans.RequisitionNumber));

return View(openInternalTransactionsWithOrders);
```

- Note: I did change variable names to make it easier for myself to follow. I'm a fan of descriptive names, even if they're long.